# Definition of ONE asp.net application? 

Tags: asp.net

How do you define **ONE** asp.net application? Does it have to be built under one solution or does it have to be deployed under one application under IIS?

Can multiple web projects be deployed under one IIS application (so that they have access to each other's session, cache etc) ?

This is just a theoretical question.

**Update:** What I am stressing on is what makes it **ONE** application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An application is how it is deployed under IIS. One application can consist of multiple projects but under IIS , all projects will combine to come out as an application.

If for one some reason, a website was divided across two solutions but during deployment it gets into one website under IIS then that's really one application and two solutions.

Saying all that , a lot of it depends on how you and your team uses this terminology. There is no black and white rule here.

Comment: great insight Benish. By the way when you say "If for one some reason, a website was divided across two solutions but during deployment it gets into one website under IIS then that's really one application and two solutions" ....do you mean one aplication /virtual directory under IIS? One Website under IIS can have multiple applications (as is usually the case)

Comment: I meant both website under IIS / virtual directories, since sometimes you ahve just one website with no virtual directories under it.

Answer (score 1):

I define an asp.net application as any web application that has been built primarily using asp.net as the technology behind it.

Comment: What I am stressing on is what makes one application under asp.net. The way it is deployed under IIS or the way it is built (as in under one solution).